# Process muliple forms in Django view

Tags: django, django-forms

I have 2 forms in my Django view. How can I do a check to see which one has been submitted?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a different `name` attribute on the submit buttons for each form, then check for that key in `request.POST` in your view.

Also don't forget to give each form a separate `prefix` attribute when you instantiate them, to avoid any possible field name collisions.

Comment: +1 for the foresight about namespace collision and prefix attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas:

- Use different action URLs for the forms, associated with different views.
- Use different action URLs for the forms, associated with the same view but with using different parameters to the view (using the URLconf)
- Use an `<input type="hidden" />` to differentiate between the forms.

Philip